# Errors with changing to drag in Unity 2D ( C#)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch, draggable

My errors are
Collider2d is a type but is used like a variable.
Cannot modify the return value of transform.posistion because it's not a variable.
Cannot implicitly convert type vector2 to float.

Heres My code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveRacket : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 30;
    public string axis = "Vertical";
    public object racket = "Racket";
    public bool touchInput = true;
    public Vector2 touchPos;





    void FixedUpdate () {

        //used to not have anything in parentheses
        //float v = Input.GetAxisRaw (axis);
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw (axis);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (0, v) * speed;
        if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            Vector3 wp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(wp.x, wp.y);
            if (Collider2D == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
            {
            this.transform.position.y =  new Vector3 (wp.y,0);

        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set values to position.y/x/z, that is the error you are getting. so instead of

```
this.transform.position.y =  new Vector3 (wp.y,0);
```

use this

```
this.transform.position =  new Vector3 (0,wp.y,0);
```

that is if you want z and x to be zero, but you get the point.

Comment: Thanks although will that fix the collider2d error also I'm in 2d so should I have the 0 for z in therre.

Comment: even though you are in 2D, the transform object still has the Z attribute (it is a vector 3: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) so you can set it, or the value you want

Comment: Thanks, do you know what I should do about collider 2d error

Comment: Sure. You are using the Collider2D as a variable here:

 if (Collider2D == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))

the way you are calling is wrong. What i think you want to do is to know if the collider of an object is being hit by the touch point. I suggest you grab the collider of the object and check with that collider, for more info:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OverlapPoint.html

ex:
getcomponent<collider2D>().OverlapPoint(touchpos) will return true or false